# I need SUM() for every operation. Any idea for not to get deadlock error?

Tags: sql, performance, deadlock

I have a web service which makes transactions for companies.
but companies have transaction amount limits.
so every time service is called it executes:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM Transactions WHERE CompanyID = 25
```

and there are 5 to ten similar calculations. But SUM operation locks the table and I get deadlock errors. there are 300 to 500 hits per second.

I found a solution in stored procedures. I calculate SUM's and write them to another summary table. But I wonder if anyone has alternative idea ? Certainly most applications need SUM of something.

best.

Comment: `...from transactions with nolock where...`

Comment: @paqogomez Are you seriously suggesting they use `with nolock` so they don't have deadlocks? This is the worst advice.

Comment: based on the information provided, yes.  Dirty reads can be an acceptable practice for many situations.

Comment: `NoLock` can be a valid solution.  Emphasis on *can*...  do you care about dirty reads?

Comment: [SQL Server NOLOCK Hint & other poor ideas.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx)

Comment: And a blog post by Aaron Bertrand where he discusses several issues with NOLOCK. It's not only Dirty reads: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: And I don't mena that it can be used. Of course it can. But there are usually other reasons for deadlocks and using NOLOCK often just hides the problem under the carpet - if it solves at all. The OP here of course has provided almost 0 details about his problem.

Comment: @AykutCanturk, please provide details. I.e. the `CREATE TABLE` statement of the table. How many rows does the table have? How many rows satisfy the `WHERE CompanyID = X` condition in average? You could add the whole procedure that gets deadlocked or at least a description of what it does (the procedure, not the query.)

Comment: @ypercube, 0 details.  Exactly my point.  Great bunch of links, very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that best solution is write stored procedures and keep running totals in another table. I implemented this solution and it works nicely. I need to give up the thought of I have to get totals from original data every time. Need to trust sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts that come to mind:

- You really should have test infrastructure that you could load test with the appropriate level of traffic. Don't implement any solutions suggested here in production without making sure you aren't making the situation worse.
- Do you have an index on CompanyID? If you don't you might be initiating a table scan with each Sum query. You could introduce an index on CompanyID/Amount, and then the query plan doesn't even need to hit the data pages. Adding extra indices slows down writes, so there is a balancing act here.
- Depending on your database software, you could make use of indexed views. Think of this of having the database precompute these sums whenever the table changes.
- It's not unusual to start denormalizing data for performance reasons when you have to deal with a heavy load. I assume the transaction table only has to deal with inserts. You could maintain a counter that you increment for each customer as transactions are created. You then don't have to touch the transaction table to verify a customer didn't exceed his quota.
- Two things to focus on when troubleshooting deadlocks: 1) Long running transaction blocks (keep em short) and 2) within a transaction block, always access your resources in the same order.
- You may find this interesting: [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). CQRS is an architecture that some use to bypass the resource contention that's inherent when you try to read and write to the same backing store under high load.